# Creating a file using Arduino and VDIP 1

Tags: arduino

I'm working at my final project for my uni and I'm using an Arduino mega 2560 and a VDIP1 module [http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_VDIP1.pdf].

At this point I managed to create a file on my USB flash drive connected to the VDIP1 and print 128 bits to it. The problem is that when I'm printing a message in the file it is stored as ascii I would like to make the file from the bytes sent.

For example if I send the byte: 0x61 I would like to create a file with the bytes source "61".

What I tried to do but I failed is:

```
 int byte1 = 0x61;
 Serial1.print ("OPW TEST5.HEX");
      Serial1.write (13);
      WaitForResponse(true, 10000);

      //
      //WRITE TO FILE
      //

      Serial1.print("WRF 1");
      Serial1.write(13);
      WaitForResponse(true, 1000);
      Serial1.print(byte1);
      Serial1.write(13);

      WaitForResponse(true, 1000);

      //
      //CLOSE THE FILE
      //

      Serial1.print("CLF TEST5.HEX");
      Serial1.write(13);

      WaitForResponse(true, 10000);
```

It's creating the file but it's not containing what I want:

HEX value : 39

ASCII value : 9

EDIT:

With your help I managed to write the raw binary to the file [I didn't known this how it's called]. But also I got into another problem.

After I plug my flash drive to the VDIP I need to run twice the program to create and write to the file to even create it.

The entire code is:

```
char incomingByte = 0;
int inPinFlow = 28;
int byte1= 0x61;

void setup(){
  pinMode(inPinFlow, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  Serial1.print("IPA");
  Serial1.write(13);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Initialization finished");  
}
void loop(){

  if (Serial.available()){

    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("command = ");
    Serial.print(incomingByte);
    Serial.println();

    if(incomingByte == '1'){

      Serial1.print("OPW TEST5.HEX");
      Serial1.write(13);

      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Open file: ");
      Serial.println();

      Serial1.print("WRF 1");
      Serial1.write(13);


      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Prepare for writing: ");
      Serial.println();

      Serial1.write(byte1);
      Serial1.write(13);


      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Write: ");
      Serial.println();
      delay(500);
      Serial1.print("CLF TEST5.HEX");
      Serial1.write(13);


      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Close file: ");
      Serial.println();

      Serial.print("END");
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your terms of source hex is confusing. It is not clear as to what you want. (at least to me) obviously you want to write something to the file. You can either print it or write it. As you have the write(13) for carriage return. Print sends the ASCII equivalent and print sends the raw binary.

Answer (score 0):

See the page [here on Serial print](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print).

From that page:

> An optional second parameter specifies the base (format) to use;
>   permitted values are BIN (binary, or base 2), OCT (octal, or base 8),
>   DEC (decimal, or base 10), HEX (hexadecimal, or base 16). For floating
>   point numbers, this parameter specifies the number of decimal places
>   to use. For example:

So perhaps try:

```
Serial.print(78, HEX) // gives "4E"
```

(I'm surprised the Arduino is able to write to a file on its own - what is the rest of the code to do that?)

Comment: Hy I know the Serial.print 's second parameter the problem is that is not what I want I have the variable int named "byte" which already store a hex number. If I put Serial1.print(byte1, HEX) it will take the value from byte1 and it will convert it in HEX. What I want is to take the value from byte1 and put in the HEX source of the file. If byte1 is 0x61 the hex source of the file I want to be 61.And the Arduino is not able to connect USB flash drivers and create files you need and MCU module which in my case is the VDIP1

Comment: your comment above 'I send the byte: 0x61 I would like to create a file with the bytes source "61".' where print(byte1, HEX) will send a binary 0x36(54d) followed by binary 0x31(49d). Which appears to be what you are asking for.

Comment: if you are looking to just store the raw binary, use .write(byte1);

Comment: Thank you so much @mpflaga now it's working almost now I realised that I have another problem. After I plug in my flash drive in the VDIP I need to run twice the algorithm to write the byte into the file other wise it will not even create the file [the algorithm contains open file write to file and close it. I will edit my post adding the full code maybe someone have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not being an expert on the VDIP1 and it being somewhat hard to find data on its USB Memory stick commands. I see from the [article and example](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/UsbMemory#.UxpMf4WTLE4) that the WRF needs to include the  (13). So I believe you should change the following line from

```
Serial1.print("WRF 1");
```

to

```
Serial1.print("WRF 2");
```

As I suspect the VDIP is not closing the file correctly.

---

note in the related [article](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,57680.0.html)

```
Serial.print(13, BYTE);
```

has been replaced with

```
Serial.write(13);
```

Comment: WRF 1 means that I'm sending 1 byte if I change it to WRF 2 that means I will send 2 bytes while I'm sending byte1 which is 0x61 the VDIP1 gets stuck while it is waiting one more byte in data mode. And regarding the Serial1.write(13); I'm using it it's sending the carriage return byte to let the VDIP1 to know that it's the end of the message

Comment: PS: First article that you linked is the main source of inspiration and he's code is doing the same as mine doesn't write at the first run after plug-in the flash drive

Comment: In lieu of an actual manual for VDIP1, I see in the article "//add 2 to the num as will also write the letter P and a return character". Where in both articles they "noOfChars +=2;" +1 for a prefix digit they add and +1 (again) for the carriage return. Both of these agree, indicating the number is inclusive of the terminating Carriage Return (13d)